# How to access complex JSON data in PHP

Tags: php, json

Here is the JSON response in which I need your help.

I need to access "age" key inside 'attribute'.

I really tried every possible ways that i could get. So can u please try to help me out :)

[image: KEY NEEDED]

Comment: Can you provide the code you have tried to access that key please?

Comment: Use json_encode  and convert it to array and then get what ever you want? Also if you can put your effort then more easy to get solution?

Comment: I tried too many steps. But still dont know what to send as none worked out.

Comment: Already used json_encode ... but its giving '{' as result

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways I can see checking the json you just provided, one is by iterating the array, and the other one is accessing it by index:

```
$json = json_decode($response);
foreach ($json as $item) {
    $value = $item->item->attribute->age->value;
    var_dump($value);
}
```

the other way:

```
$value = $json[0]->item->attribute->age->value;
```

Comment: Thanks .. Please have a look at these screenshots. Its the code http://prntscr.com/71w7qr    &   this is the response http://prntscr.com/71w8i7

Answer (score 0):

Another option, is that when you call json_decode by default you get a php object, however, if you add an optional boolean parameter you get an array which can be easier in situations like this to access nested elements.

```
// $data is the original json string
$json = json_decode($data, true);
print_r($json);
```

Comment: If you're already doing that, then please update your question with a print_r or var_dump of the json data immediately after you've done your json_decode.  The answers you've gotten previously assumed you did not decode to an array